# Amazon and Wikipedia not responsive on desktop browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

[image: Stackoverflow] works fine, but not [image: Amazon.com] and [image: Wikipedia] (tried in Chrome and Firefox).

Responsive Amazon.com looks like [image: this] in my phone.

Why aren't they responsive in my Chrome/Firefox desktop browser?

Answer (score 1):

It is because of different ways that those websites implement responsive design. StackOverflow is turning into mobile view after the windows is smaller. But amazon.de for example does not respond to changing window size, but to the change of browser's user-agent. I just installed in my Chrome [add-on to change user-agent](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg/related) and changed it to some generic android browser user-agent. Then reloaded amazon.de website and it turned into mobile version - doesn't matter the window size.

So, some websites are not fully responsive to changing window size. Some also check if you're really on a mobile device by looking at browser's user-agent, so just changing the window size will not let you see if there is mobile version and some respond only to user-agent change, doesn't matter size of the window as long as your user-agent says "I'm a mobile browser".

Please keep in mind that Amazon turns into mobile version without change in URL address. There is no `m.amazon.de` or `amazon.de/m/`, it's still `amazon.de`. So it's not different page, it's still responsive design - just it's responsive to something more than mere window's size change, it checks user-agent to determine if the browser is mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Device mode is enabled. Try CTRL+SHIFT+M to disable it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/
for more info.